# Struct default value initialization in C++14

Tags: c++, class, struct, c++14

What would be the best way to do default initialization for this struct in a header file in C++14?

```
struct ValueStruct
{
  int m_Number;
  double m_arrValues[10];
};
```

1: Brace initialization

```
struct ValueStruct
{
  int m_Number= -1;
  double m_arrValues[10] = { -1, -1 ...... -1 };
};
```

2: I create a constructor and then initialize everything there. By using a for loop for array.

Comment: A constructor will mean it's no longer aggregate initialized (and you'll find it hard to pass an initializer for the array into the c'tor). Personally, I think default values should *always* be specified in a default member initializer, even when constructors are present.

Comment: Can you remove the 2 instances of `**`? Someone might misread this as some sort of pointer notation. (I can't make this edit because it's only 4 characters.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on your needs. If you only need to initialize the array, you can use the brace initialization, which will also be easier to read. The constructor however brings in more flexibility if you need to do more actions during the initialization of your struct. It will also be more useful and easier to use a constructor if your array gets bigger, which will make the brace initialization a bit more difficult and repetitive.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have any specific requirements then you can simply initialize the structure with {}, but you cannot initialize the way you've done it. First, you have to create an object for the structure and then you've to initialize it.

Eg:
ValueStruct d_VS = {};

Comment: The way I have done it right now works just fine. I do not intend to let the client of this structure give default values. The default values should be defined by the structure itself